# Possible 4 bit combinations using successive shifts

Tags: sequence, shift, graph-traversal

I'm trying to figure out the number of possible combinations using 4 bits and successive shifts. I have an array of 4 light sensors reading a paper strip with white and black marks. I want to figure out its position.

I need to know the maximum number of non repeating, unique possibilities, I tried to figure it out manually but cant get past 14. I want to reach 16 if its possible.

Here is my sequence:

```
0000
0001
0010
0100
1001
0011
0110
1101
1011
0111
1111
1110
1100
1000
```

BTW I'm missing `0101` and `1010`

Comment: Somehow related to [Maximum Length Sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_length_sequence)? It should be 2^N-1, hence 15.

Comment: @Cthulhu 15 transitions, but 16 nodes.

Answer (score 1):

```
0000 0001 0011 0111 // 0 1 3 7
1111 1110 1100 1001 // F E C 9
0010 0101 1011 0110 // 2 5 B 6
1101 1010 0100 1000 // D A 4 8
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, asking here is a great experience.